# enable/disable data grid columns using ivalue convertor in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I am working on a silverlight application using MVVM. My requirements is to display existing user data in data grid so that first two columns remains non-editable and rest will be editable.

At start datagrid loads data from database, at that point if user click on data grid first two columns should be non-editable.

After that user insert a new row (i create a button, when that is clicked a new row is added at the bottom of the grid) all columns should be editable including first two. Now user can click Add row buttons more than once, point is rows created by Add button click should be editable.

I am stuck at this problem since yesterday any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know Silverlight but I think the following should work:
On your command to add a new row, set a flag like "AllRowsEditable" to true and throw a PropertyChanged for this Property. In your view you bind the IsReadonly property of the first two columns to that "AllRowsEditable" property.

EDIT: Write a ViewModel for your DataGrid items. For example "RowViewModel". To have a good structure I would introduce two properties like "IsFirstPropertyReadOnly" and "IsSecondPropertyReadOnly" in that ViewModel. "...firstProperty..." is your properties name. In your XAML you can bind to this properties. In your first initialization you load the items and set the property values to true. All items added after that you set that properties to false.

Comment: but in that case, the first two columns of newly added row also get IsReadOnly = True

Comment: Correct, how should it act if the user add multiple new rows?

Comment: either the newly inserted row is single or multiple, all the columns of data grid should be editable

Comment: Please update your question post, I dont get it. You have 3 cases. Case 1: you haven´t new row. Case 2: you have one new row. Case 3: after you added a new row, you add a second new row. Which rows should be when editable?

Comment: i updated my question, sorry for late updation weekend you know :)

Comment: nice suggestion, it worked
i have to customize it a bit, but thanks for the idea :)